# Extra White Space Above the Footer Div

Tags: html, css

When I started Googling this question I saw the plethora of SO questions that are similar. But I tried them all and no luck.

I am getting a white margin from somewhere. Not sure where.

Here is a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/ayezee33/smxdewam/

Here is what I have tried.

- Adding margin:0; and padding:0; to the html and body.
- Linked up normalize.css
- Added 0 margin on the block level element and child element
- Found a user agent stylesheet inserting 8px margin (Chrome)
- Used the !important call to override that
- Noticed user agent stylesheet was applying block to my  and
  tried to override that but I am sure I actually want that.

Any help would be great. I am going crazy trying to figure this out.

Apparently I need to add code to post this question?

```
<header>
    <h1>Building blocks are important!</h1>
    <p>This website serves as my test to showcase my coding abilities</p>
        <div id="cta">
            <input id="cta" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit">Learn More</button>
        </div>  
</header>   

<div class="callout">
    <p>Testing this call out section</p>

</div>  


.callout {
display:block;
max-width:100%;
height:5em;
background:#000;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.callout p {
line-height:5em;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of white space in that fiddle, you're going to have to be more specific with which one you have an issue with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is coming from the margin on your `#cta`:

```
  margin: 1em auto;
```

Simplify your css too, I feel like you don't need most of your rules.

Comment: Ah, I feel dumb. Thank you. That indeed was the issue. I am self taught and trying to get in a better habit of clean code. Any id that needs special cleansing? Or just a general tidying up of things?

Comment: np. Also don't use ids for targeting css. Use classes instead. Use ids only for JavaScript hooks. IDs are just not flexible for modular development. Also, please accept the answer if the answer helped you.

Comment: and stay away from hacks as much as possible. Write the simplest css and then progressively enhance your css. Use hacks sparsely and let the document render naturally. That guarantees consistent rendering across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The margin on the `#cta` DIV is the one thats causing the white-space. You can add `overflow:hidden` to the header, that would fix the issue.

```
<nav>
    <div id="main-nav">
        <img src="img/logo.jpg" />
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</nav>

<header>
    <h1>Building blocks are important!</h1>
    <div id="cta">
        <input id="cta" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <button type="submit">Learn More</button>
    </div>
</header>   

<div class="callout">
    <p>Testing this call out section</p>

</div>  

header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```